# How to remove scrollbar from tables

Tags: html, css, sass

I am making a table that gets data from datatables in ruby on rails. 
I want the rows to autofit if the browser is smaller, instead of making a scrollbar on the width. 
The scrollbar should never come no matter what.

I tried some css like table-layout: fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to your table

```
table-layout: auto;
overflow: hidden;
```